# If $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} A & 0 \\ 0 & A \\ \end{array}} \right) \ge 0$ then $A \ge 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$  and $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   A & 0  \\
   0 & A  \\
\end{array}} \right) \ge 0$

Can we prove that $A \ge 0$?

Comment: What does your first line mean?

Comment: A matrix can not be greater than or equal to a real number. They are not comparable. Do you maybe mean that the determinant of the matrix is greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: @Plankton $A\geq 0$ is a common way to write "The matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite", I assume that's what is meant in both cases above.

Comment: Or maybe it's a positive operator.

Comment: Are you saying the determinant is bigger than 0? And is $A$ real? If so, then this is false, just take the negative of the identity matrix.

Comment: @Plankton If $A \ge 0$ i.e $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is positive, assume $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, take $(x^T, x^T)^T$ to test the diagonal matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x^T & x^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ x\end{pmatrix} = 2x^TAx \geq 0$$
implies that $x^TAx \geq 0$, i.e., $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 2):

So $\forall\ \textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we have $\textbf{x}^T\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}\textbf{x}\geq0$. Let $\textbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary, we want to show $\textbf{y}^TA\textbf{y}\geq0$. To this end, let $\textbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $\textbf{x}=\left(\begin{array}{c}\textbf{y}\\ \textbf{0}\end{array}\right)$. Then
$$\textbf{x}^T\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}\textbf{x}\geq0 \Rightarrow \left(\textbf{y}^T\ \  \textbf{0}^T\right)\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ 0 & A\end{pmatrix}\left(\begin{array}{c}\textbf{y}\\ \textbf{0}\end{array}\right)\geq0 \Rightarrow \textbf{y}^TA\textbf{y}\geq0.$$