# If $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} A & B \\ B & A \\ \end{array}} \right) \ge 0 \Rightarrow A \ge B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_n$ and $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   A & B  \\
   B & A  \\
\end{array}} \right) \ge 0$

Why does $A \ge B$ ?

Comment: With $A\geq B$, do you mean that $A-B$ is positive semi-definite? Your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545981/if-left-beginarray20c-a-0-0-a-endarray-right-ge-0/1546007#1546007) raised similar questions, so why is there again so little information in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x$ be given. Then
$$
0\le \pmatrix{x\\-x}^T\pmatrix{A&B\\B&A}\pmatrix{x\\-x}
 = 2x^TAx - 2x^TBx,
$$
This implies
$$
x^T(A-B)x\ge0
$$
for all $x$, hence $A\ge B$.

Answer (score -5):

If you take Determinant of the above matrix, it becomes,

$A^2-B^2 \ge 0$

Square of any number is positive and to yield the number greater than zero, A should be always greater than B.

Hence $A\ge B$

Comment: this answer is wrong in so many ways

Comment: $A$, $B$ are matrices, not real numbers.

Comment: Even, if you take this interpretation:
$$
A = -5 \wedge B=1 \Rightarrow A^2 - B^2 \geq 0
$$
So $-5 > 1$, cause squares are positive?